# Как исправить ошибку: TypeError: требуется целое число (полученная строка типа) / tkinter, json

Tags: python, json, tkinter

Возникла проблема с чтением файла, а именно json. Хочу получить данные из него, но что-то не так. Работаю вдобавок с модулем tkinter.

Открываю файл:

```
with open("account.json", "r") as authFile:
                data = json.load(authFile)
```

Сам json:

```
{
    "profile":[{
      "token": "!",
      "group_id": "!"
    }] 
}
```

С самим модулем tkinter, когда я нажимаю кнопку "Авторизация", происходит ошибка:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Степан\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:/Users/Степан/Desktop/VkClient/Main.py", line 82, in functionButtonAuth
    with open("account.json", "r") as authFile:
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

А вот сама функция:

```
def functionButtonAuth():

        root = Tk()
        root.geometry('400x500')
        root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        root.title('Авторизация')
        root.iconbitmap(r'iconAuth.ico')

        with open("account.json", "r") as authFile:
                data = json.load(authFile)

        vk_session = VkApi(token=data['profile']['token'])
        longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, data['profile']['group_id'])
        vk = vk_session.get_api()

        try:
                vk_session.auth()
        except vk_api.AuthError as error_msg:
                print(error_msg)

        root.mainloop()
```

Заранее говорю, в ошибке я заметил ключевое слово `str`, я пробовал, всё тоже самое. Прошу, подскажите, что делать.

Comment: Попробовал создать другой скрипт, написал обычное чтение файла вместе с выводом `print`, работает без ошибок. Попробовал с основным кодом, та же самая ошибка.

Comment: Вы нигде функцию open случайно не переопределили?

Comment: Функция open нигде случайно не переопределена?

Comment: @insolor, это как понять?

Comment: Переопределена = вы создали функцию с таким же именем у себя в скрипте

Comment: @insolor, Нету. У меня ни одного `open` нету даже вообще.

Comment: @insolor, https://pastebin.com/9C1Gc2kz. Вот весь код, на всякий случай.

Comment: Вам говорили, что импортировать через звёздочку не хорошо?) похоже это как раз тот случай: в одном из подключённых модулей есть функция open, которая у вас перекрыла системный open

Comment: @insolor, На счёт звёздочки не слышал)) Просто так удобно, сразу импортировать весь модуль. Сейчас попробую, отпишу.

Comment: @insolor, Да, спасибо Вам большое! Возьму на заметку!